# Underline some characters in a String

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have the following problem:

My JavaScript code shows a display value this way:

```
d3.select("#" + uiElement).html("")
                        .append("span").attr("class", "displayvalue").html(stringToUse);
```

stringtoUse is the value to show, my issue is to underline that string, but some times, it's not required underline all the string but all except the first character of it.
In your opinion what's the best way to do so?

Comment: "_underline all the string but all except the first char of it_" this sounds like something you can fix with proper CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS `first-letter` pseudo element. Make your all text underlined and then apply css to it as:

```
#element::first-letter
{ 
text-decoration:none !important:
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) to use.

By simple pure javascript:

```
var text = document.getElementById("element").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = text.substring(0,1)+"<u>"+text.substring(1)+"</u>";
```

Comment: How can I make it all underlined using Javascript?

Comment: Yes it is depreciated in html 4 but works in all modern browser. If you are not in favour of `<u>` you can use `text.substring(0,1)+"<span style='text-decoaration:underline'>"+text.substring(1)+"</span>";` or `text.substring(0,1)+"<span class='underlineCSS'>"+text.substring(1)+"</span>";` @Edge7

Comment: <span style='text-decoration:underline'> works fine.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to format any javascript innerHTML using CSS directly, without hassling around in javascript:

The javascript:

```
function test(){
document.getElementById('pp').innerHTML = 'here is pp';
document.getElementById('qq').innerHTML = 'here is qq';
}
```

The HTML:

```
<p style = 'whatever'>
<a id = 'pp'></a>
<a id = 'qq' style = 'color:red; text-decoration: underline;' ></a>
</p>
  <script>
  test()
  </script>
```

This works with or without a wrapper like `<p>`.